# Sophos Antivirus for Mac - Update preference disabled in Mac OSX Lion

Tags: anti-virus, sophos

I use Sophos Antivirus on my Mac (running Lion 10.7.5) and I am not able to change **Update Settings** as it is greyed out. I clicked on the Lock icon on the bottom portion, entered my password (administrator account) and still I find it greyed out. Here is the image for reference.

[image: Autoupdate settings greyed out]

What should I do that will allow me to change these settings?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to change a configuration file, specifically `iconn.cfg`. Inside this file try changing the line `AllowLocalConfig = 0` to `AllowLocalConfig = 1` (under `[PPI.WebConfig_Primary]` section).

On macOS, it's located in:

- `/Library/Sophos Anti-Virus`

On Windows it's in (depending on the operating system):

- `\Program files\Sophos\AutoUpdate\Config`
- `\ProgramData\Sophos\AutoUpdate\Config`

Source: [Edit local config - Endpoint 9.5/9.7](https://community.sophos.com/products/endpoint-security-control/f/sophos-endpoint-software/9059/edit-local-config---endpoint-9-5-9-7).

Comment: But can you tell me where this iconn.cfg file resides in Mac OSX Lion? The source link you have given has the answer for Windows OS

Comment: I'm not using Sophos so I might be wrong, but try looking for `Library/preferences/com.sophos.sau.plist` on a Mac

Comment: The plist was found under /Library/Sophos\ Anti-Virus/ but even after adding <key>AllowLocalConfig</key> <string>1</string> I could not get the auto update settings enabled :-(

Comment: Then probably you will have more luck contacting their support..